# CSRF verfication failed, but only with IE9

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I have set up CSRF as described in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) (using Django 1.3). It works with FF and Safari, but on IE9 I get

```
<div id="summary">
<h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
<p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>
</div>
```

In the response headers of the Ajax request I find

```
Set-Cookie  csrftoken=8db3637951243ffb591e6b2d6998ed03; expires=Fri, 14-Sep-2012 08:01:52 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

It works in IE9 when using it in a normal Form (i.e. no Ajax involved).

I am using Django behind nginx/1.1.2.

Any hints what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

If your form is inside an iframe, the probable reason is IE's default policy of blocking third-party cookies. You could

- not use an iframe,
- bring the iframed page under the same domain as the main page,
- disable CSRF for that particular form using the [@csrf_exempt decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt), or
- use HTTP headers to tell the browser to allow third-party cookies (see work-around #3 in [Chase Seibert's excellent explanation of this issue](http://bitkickers.blogspot.com/2011/06/django-csrf-verification-failed-in-ie.html)).

Django's ticket [#17157](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17157) proposes to add a note about this issue in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, the problem for me was that I did not specify the form action attribute. IE apparantly doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 1):

In Django's ticket [#17157](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17157) (thanks @akaihola for the link) it's stated that the problem is that Internet Explorer blocks third-party cookies by default. So you can enable third-party cookies for all sites or only for your site in browser settings.
Here is how to do that in IE 7 (from [this link](http://feedjit.com/static/howToEnableThirdPartyCookies.html)):

1. Click the "Tools" menu
2. Click "Internet Options"
3. Select the "Privacy" tab

Option 1: To enable third-party cookies for all sites

1. Click "Advanced"
2. Select "Override automatic cookie handling"
3. Select the "Accept" button under "Third-party Cookies" and click "OK"

OR

Option 2: To enable third-party cookies just for Feedjit.com

1. Click "Sites"
2. Add "*your-domain.com*" and click "Allow"
3. Click "OK"
4. Select the "Accept" button under "Third-party Cookies" and click "OK"